# Incrmenting a Cookies with PHP (Beginner Question)

Tags: php, cookies, count, conditional-statements, setcookie

I have used sessions before but never cookies. I would like to use cookies for two reasons:
1) it's something new to learn
2) I would like to have the cookie expire in an hour or so (i know in the code example it expires in 40 sec)

I am trying to write a basic if statement that

```
      if($counter=="1") { //do this second 
} 
        elseif ($counter >="2") { //do this every time after the first and second
} 
        else {// this is the first action as counter is zero
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to set the cookie:

```
 // if cookie doesnt exsist, set the default
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["counter_cookie"])) {
        $counter = setcookie("counter_cookie", 0 ,time()+40);

    }

    // increment it
     $counter++;



    // save it
     setcookie("counter_cookie", $counter,time()+40);
     $counter = $_COOKIE["counter_cookie"];
```

The problem is that the counter will be set from 0 to 1 but won't be set from 1 to 2 and so on. Any help would be great I know this is a really simple stupid question :|

Thanks!

Comment: Who stole the cookies from the cookie jar?

Comment: you stole the cookie for the cookie jar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely related to this line:

```
$counter = setcookie("counter_cookie", 0 ,time()+40);
```

It appears you are expecting setcookie to return a value, but that isn't going to happen. Instead, setcookie will simply return a boolean true on success and false on failure.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

You could try rewriting it like this to achieve the desired effect:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["counter_cookie"]))
{
  $counter = $_COOKIE["counter_cookie"];
}
else
{
  $counter = 0;
}
$counter++
setcookie("counter_cookie", $counter ,time()+40);
```

Comment: thanks I got it working by using 
    // if it doesnt, set the default
 if(!isset($_COOKIE["counter_cookie"])) {
  setcookie("counter_cookie", 0 ,time()+40);
   
 }
 //get the value of the counter
  $counter = $_COOKIE["counter_cookie"];

Comment: You were editing it at the same time I was, essentially my edit does the same thing it just get the value of the cookie after it's been set. then adds it. Thanks again for your help